# What in the world is WebsiteOS?

Tags: web-hosting, management, control-panel

*Note: This question was asked at Software_Recommendations but that wasn't the correct place for it. I'm posting this question here as a result.*

I recently did a website project for a client and when it was time to upload the site to his hosting, he gave me the access to a rather bizzarre looking control panel. It's called **WebsiteOS 4** and that's all I know about it so far.

[image: Inside WebsiteOS 4]
The documentation page fails to load properly. (I think there's a bug there)

A google search only revealed the login page of all hosts that provide websiteos which doesn't help. For the record, this client is using bluegenesis who in 2016 is highlighting their service of "Fax to Email" starting at $9.99 folks! No kidding, I just took the screenshot.

[image: Home page of Bluegenesis]

My primary objective is to find some information on WebsiteOS 4. What it is? When did it came out? Why is it being used today? Does anyone know about this? I would like to convince the client to move away from it and towards a modern host and I need some hard facts for it.

Comment: Sorry but this question is too board, opinionated and off-topic because the question involves pros and cons of a control panel, and recommendations on software, services and resources are considered off-topic. If you are considering a hosting company and have a question about the services or software they use, you should direct your questions to them, if you don't have faith in them providing simple information as this then you should not consider their services.

Comment: You may be able to save this question by simplifying your questions to more specific questions about WebOS. Additional too many questions within one question can be considered too board so you might have to split your questions up to singular questions because 'What is WebOS' is already asking a lot from the community.

Comment: I'm looking for information about this software if anyone knew or used it in the past.

Comment: Its a hosting control panel similar to cpanel and plesk, but you most likely know this already and want further details which makes the question extremely broad because your question isn't specific enough.For general discussion our chat channel is best.